# JSON list shows as [ ] even if it contains objects?

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, flask

I'm trying to get a list of quantities (identified as cantidad) chosen of each product (as id) to my flask controller. Since wtform didn't adapted well to my needs I had to use json and jQuery, but no matter what I do, the list of objects is seen as empty in the controller, even if in the frontend it does has something inside.
This is the JavaScript:

This function posts the order which should be a list of quantities with id assigned:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  function setPedido(order){
    console.log(order);
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{url_for('main.pedido')}}",
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(order),
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.redirect) {
          window.location.href = response.redirect;
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

When "pedido" (order) button is clicked, gets all assigned quantities and their respective product IDs:

```
  $(".btnPedido").click(function(){
    var order = []

    $(function() {
      var lines = $(".btnAgregar.active")
      for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        console.log(lines[i]);
        order.push({ 
          'id': $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.btnPedido').val(), 
          'cantidad' : $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.inpCantidad').val()
        });
      }
    });
    setPedido(order);
  });
```

This marks each quantity input as ready to order:

```
  $(".btnAgregar").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0){
      $(this).val(1);
      $(this).text("Agregado");
    }else{
      $(this).val(0);
      $(this).text("Agregar");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-info btn-success active');
  });

</script>
```

This shows in the console:

[image: Console]

And this in flask controller (notice data):

[image: Flask]

Comment: Have you tried to log `JSON.stringify(order)` to check that it functions are you're expecting it to? Can you also check the outgoing request in your web browser to see if the data is in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at this function, paying better attention i declared a function inside another function, wich is executed at a different scope than setPedido(order), at wich point it stills empty.
To make it worse, the console.log inside the inner function where misleading.

```
$(".btnPedido").click(function(){
    var order = []

    $(function() {
      var lines = $(".btnAgregar.active")
      for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        console.log(lines[i]);
        order.push({ 
          'id': $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.btnPedido').val(), 
          'cantidad' : $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.inpCantidad').val()
        });
      }
    });
    setPedido(order);
  });
```

The correct way to do it is:

```
$(".btnPedido").click(function(){
      var order = []
      var lines = $(".btnAgregar.active")
      for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        console.log(lines[i]);
        order.push({ 
          'id': $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.btnPedido').val(), 
          'cantidad' : $(lines[i]).closest("tr").find('.inpCantidad').val()
        });
      }
    setPedido(order);
  });
```